# Old projects compatible with Java 7

Tags: java, backwards-compatibility, java-7, java-6

My old projects use Java 6 (1.6), and I don't know when I update (Java 7), they can run fine ?

Answer (score 12):

There is an [official list](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/compatibility-417013.html) of known incompatibilities between java 6 and java 7 from Oracle (including descriptions of both binary and source-level incompatibilities in public APIs).

Also you can look at the independent analysis of API changes in the Java API Tracker project: http://abi-laboratory.pro/java/tracker/timeline/jre/

The report is generated by the *[japi-compliance-checker](https://github.com/lvc/japi-compliance-checker)* tool.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

They *should* do, yes. Java has a reasonably strong history of backward compatibility. However, if these are in any way *important* projects you should still perform a thorough test pass before deploying anywhere production-like.

Comment: +1. Unfortunately the current release (Update 0) has some problems (visible in Lucene/Solr for example: http://lucene.apache.org/#28+July+2011+-+WARNING%3A+Index+corruption+and+crashes+in+Apache+Lucene+Core+%2F+Apache+Solr+with+Java+7)

Comment: @rebecca: That depends - does it have anything you know you *want* in it, either in terms of language, API or VM improvements? It's very hard for me to give concrete advice without knowing all about your project. *Personally* I'd want to move to Java 7 to use the new language features, but I don't know your situation or predilections.

Comment: @Jon, predilection, a new word for me. I like it.;)

Comment: @Jon: I use JDK for J2SE and J2EE projects.

Comment: @Joachim: Yikes - I hadn't heard about that. Nasty.

Comment: @rebecca: Sure, but that doesn't really say whether the projects you're writing would benefit from any of the new API features, or whether you personally want to start using the new language features.

Comment: @Joachim, very interesting.  Is there an accessible explanation on what instructions trigger this bug?

Comment: @Thorbjørn: I only know what I linked to. The closest to this are [these](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7070134) [three](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7044738) [bugs](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7068051) on the Java bugtracker. And as always with HotSpot bugs, the conditions to reproduce it are fairly non-trivial.

Comment: @JonSkeet new language features aren't the most important reason to update to Java 7.  Java 6 has reached EOL, and so updating is extremely important in terms of security.

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any compatibility differences as the JVM is basically the same. However it is early days so there may be subtle differences which cause a problem which people are not yet aware of.

e.g. Eclipse looks at the Supplier in the java.exe on Windows and sets the command line arguments differently for different suppliers.  It has a problem with Java 6 update 22 because Oracle wanted to change it from "Sun" to "Oracle". I believe this has been changed so it is "Oracle" in Java 7 (but still "Sun" for Java 6)

My point being, that if you write generic Java code, you shouldn't have a problem.  However, if you are doing something a bit unusual, you are likely to need to re-test your application.

Comment: Yes, our biggest bug so far is that we do a Java vendor check that now fails (and that was really just legacy to block IE Java once upon a time).

Answer (score 1):

As was already stated backward compatibility is a very important aspect in new Java releases, so in general there should be no problems in switching to a newer Java version. In this case,  however, Java 7 seems to have a few bugs in the new hotspot compiler optimizations. The Apache Software Foundation  has issued a warning that their products Lucene and Solr are affected by these bugs.

http://lucene.apache.org/#28+July+2011+-+WARNING%3A+Index+corruption+and+crashes+in+Apache+Lucene+Core+%2F+Apache+Solr+with+Java+7

The affected loop optimizations can be switched off by starting java with `-XX:-UseLoopPredicate`.

Comment: Its worth nothing that the latest versions of Java 6 also have this bug.

Comment: @Peter: That's right, but the appropriate option is off by default in Java 6.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIS [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7_.28July_28.2C_2011.29), there's no Java 6 features which get deprecated in Java 7 so yes, your project should run fine.