# What are the pitfalls when upgrading to Java 7

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I am switching an enterprise application built on Spring 3.1.0, Hibernate 3.6.0 from Java 6 32bit to Java 7 64 bit.
Has anybody done that? Any problems? Are there any resources on the subject?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to switch then compare your two versions under the same test environment.

Comment: Just found this (a bit old) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6870753/old-projects-compatible-with-java-7

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are the pitfalls I know about:

- You might have to upgrade your IDE to be able to enable Java 7 features.
- Make sure that command line tools and your IDE use the same Java version. If you're using Maven, for example, look into `$HOME/.mavenrc` and/or check the environment variable `JAVA_HOME`
- Check the source/target options of the Java compiler.
- Java 7 supports generics better than Java 6 so some code will now compile that failed with Java 6
- The 64bit version of Java uses a lot more memory than the 32bit version
- The first release of Java 7 had a severe bug in the JIT compiler which broke Lucene. Use at least b2 or better.

Answer (score 6):

Java 7 uses the newer JAXB 2.2 instead of 2.1 (the full change on the XML stack is described [here](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/03/new-xml-stack-in-jdk-7.html)). These versions are not compatible on generated code for Boolean getters and setters!